# a topological space with finite integer first cohomology group?

Tags: algebraic-topology

One more problem preparing for a PhD exam! It states "describe a space such that $H^1(X,Z)=Z_5$." I thought this was impossible by the universal coefficient theorem since $H_0(X;Z)$ is always free, and $HOM(H_1(X,Z),Z)$ is free then $H^1(X,Z)$ is also free. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: You're correct. Perhaps the intended problem was about $H_1$.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. That problem is a lot easier :)